# Qt resource system bug in qt 4.8.3

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Qt 4.8.3 Open Source with Qt Creator 2.6.0 on Windows 8 Pro x64. The compiler I'm using is MingW 4.4.

I've an old project that I built using Qt 4.8.0. The project has a resource file named `Resource.qrc`. The project compiled fine in Qt 4.8.0 and I could access everything that I mentioned in the resource file.

But in Qt 4.8.3 I can't compile the same project. Qt 4.8.3 doesn't seem to be able to compile resource file. Here is the part of the output that tried to compile `Resource.qrc` file:

```
bin\rcc.exe -name Resource ..\Source\Resource.qrc -o release\qrc_Resource.cpp
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `E:/Programs/Version Control/Sources/Spadetrump/Release'
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, bin\rcc.exe -name Resource ..\Source\Resource.qrc -o release\qrc_Resource.cpp, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release/qrc_Resource.cpp] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
00:08:10: The process "C:\MingW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Spadetrump (target: Desktop)
When executing step 'Make'
```

It was a clean build. If I execute `rcc.exe` with the exact same arguments and with absolute path, `qrc_Resource.cpp` is generated.

I tried the above with a fresh new Qt GUI application and the result is same.

Any idea what's wrong with Qt 4.8.3?

Comment: Check the path you placed in the RESOURCE variable in the .pro file is correct.

Comment: @LucaCarlon: yes it is correct. In fact, I've added the resource file using Qt creator.

Comment: Windows 8 is not supported anyway: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/supported-platforms.html. Does it work for you on a supported version of Windows?

Comment: Also, did you download the compiled version or did you compile Qt yourself for that platform?

Comment: @LucaCarlon: i didn't try 4.8.3 in any other version of Windows. The Qt library I have downloaded is the compiled one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the exact same issues as you with the same setup, expect for the windows version which is xp for me. The problem is that the rcc.exe cannot be found, because an incorrect path is used for that call.

There is a bugreport at qt-projects for this problem: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-27237

The workarround proposed by Daniel Frömmel did the trick for me:

> 1) open the qmake.conf of your platform (for me its C:\Qt\4.8.3\mkspecs\win32-g++)
>   2) search for QMAKE_IDC
>   3) add the following line after the QMAKE_IDC line: 
>   QMAKE_RCC   = $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]$${DIR_SEPARATOR}rcc.exe
>   4) save file and clsoe
>   5) restart all your dev tools and remove all auto generated Makefiles
>   6) recompile

Comment: `QMAKE_IDC` is not present in my file.